# htaccess mod rewrite and slash after index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

but perhaps because of apache update to version 2.4.23 this one stopped working and browser returns message `file not found`.

I found out, that URL

`example.com/auth/login`

searches for `index.php` under `{document_root}/auth/login` directory and not directly in `{document_root}` and therefore it's not working. Putting directly `%{DOCUMENT_ROOR}` variable before `index.php` doesn't work, it looks like apache thinks, that document root is the one taken from URL.

How can I rewrite it to index.php with whole path put after index.php?

EDIT
I'm using fcgi and this is my vhost file:

```
<Directory "/Users/pogo/Development/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName dh
    ServerAlias *.dh

    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/pogo/Development/www/%-2.0.%-1/%0/www"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    RewriteEngine On

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/var/run/php5/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: specify where the htaccess is.

Comment: @Deadooshka directly in document root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Notice `/index.php` instead of `./index.php`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I got same result

Comment: Nope, in .htaccess is just this. I edited my question and posted my apache vhost configuration.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: yes, it is enabled (actually other vhosts which are rewritten to index.php without $1 are working just fine)

Comment: In that I suggest you enable `RewriteLog` and check rewrite log to see what is going on.

Comment: looks like the problem is the slash right after 'index.php', if I put $1 e.g. like `?a=$1`, it works, but sadly I can't get rid of it, because it's pretty old project and on production server it works (so far)

Comment: Add `AcceptPathInfo On` line on top of your .htaccess

Comment: if you want to use `/` I think you need to add `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the top of the htaccess file

Comment: @anubhava it looks like `AcceptPathInfo` should do the work (so I accepted your answer), but as long as I am using fcgi, there were some other issues to make this option turned on and I was not able to do it in reasonable time, so for now it's easier to modify my local copy of this project to manage URLs in different way. Anyway, I appreciate your help, thanks!